# Class Run in Background

Tags: java, class

I making an application in java SE.And I want to make a class that always run on background and using it own thread not the main thread that my main class using. Is this possible in java SE? as in android we can do this task with the help of service class.

Comment: Take a look to concurrency in java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do it in java SE.
You need to implement Runnable and put your code to method run()

For example:

```
public final class ThreadExample implements Runnable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadExample());
    thread.start();
    System.out.println("Exit the main");
  }

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Current time: " + (new Date()).getTime());
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```